# Cannot sign app in Xcode CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED

Tags: xcode, cocoa

I have downloaded and installed the WWDR certificate.  I have tried setting it to Always Trust *and* system defaults.

When I try to archive my app I get the CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED error.

If I try signing manually I get the same:

> /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign "3rd Party Mac Developer Application:
>   XX XXX-XXX"
>   /Users/XXX/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/XXX-fivqootinaolitdbpxccqykoaoqs/ArchiveIntermediates/XXX/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Users/XXX/Applications/XXX.app
>
> /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-fivqootinaolitdbpxccqykoaoqs/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Users/xxx/Applications/xxx.app:
>   replacing invalid existing signature
>   /Users/xxx/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/xxx-fivqootinaolitdbpxccqykoaoqs/ArchiveIntermediates/xxx/InstallationBuildProductsLocation/Users/xxx/Applications/xxx.app:
>   CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED

**BUT**

If I use

> sudo /usr/bin/codesign --force --sign

Then it works....

The key is installed in keychain access in the 'login' chain.

Comment: I get the same thing.  I've tried explicitly trusting the WWDR certificate as well as restoring it to system defaults.  I've run KeyChain First Aid and repaired any problems.  I've also repaired permission issues on the disk.  None of this has helped.  Like you, running sudo works.  Any luck on your end?

Answer (score 4):

Obishawn used one of the suggestions provided by Apple in the following steps published to troubleshoot this error - [How do I resolve the CodeSign error: CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED?](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#technotes/tn2250/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40009933-CH1-TNTAG19)
.
For others experiencing this build error -

> CSSMERR_TP_NOT_TRUSTED

the above guide covers a more broad range of potential causes. The error can also occur at Xcode Archive > Share, Validate, or Submit time, and the above steps to resolve it are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, I finally figured mine out.  I had the WWDR certificate in my login keychain and my System keychain.  I deleted both and reimported a fresh one from Apple and everything works now.  I can codesign without using sudo and MonoDevelop can fully compile for distribution and upload to my devices.

Answer (score 1):

My two cents on that problem :
I had to fight with it for some hours. Here are what I had to fix to have codesign do its job :

- **Ensure that certificates are not duplicated** between the login and the system keychain
- **Ensure no old / expired / revoked versions of the certificates exist** in any keychain
- **Ensure all certificates have "system default" trust policy**. If one is set to "always trust", then codesign will fail.

This last point was found on a machine that was migrated to Xcode 8.2 recently. It might be a new behavior of Xcode 8.